# C# SpectreConsole: is there a way to create a string without outputting it?

Tags: c#, console

I would like to create a Spectre-formatted string and then do something else with it (write it to a file, email it, put it in an exception message). Is this possible? Thanks -- Jon

Answer (score 1):

There is a extension method for this, [RemoveMarkup](https://spectreconsole.net/api/spectre.console/stringextensions/29bfb33e).

```cs
string firstName = "Jim";
string someMarkup = $"Hello [cyan]{firstName}[/]";
AnsiConsole.MarkupLine(someMarkup);
string stripped = someMarkup.RemoveMarkup();
Console.WriteLine(stripped);
```